# How to stop Validation from firing when I open modal dialog with required fields on Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I cannot comprehend JSF lifecycle for this particular case.

I'm trying to develop a simple modal CRUD with Primefaces 6.0, and I'm having problems with the beheaviour of the add/edit modal.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

**Add**

1. Click add button
2. Add/Edit dialog opens
3. InputText "field1" is disabled=false

**Edit**

1. Click edit button
2. Add/Edit dialog opens
3. InputText "field1" is disabled=true

So for this I linked "field1" **disabled** property to **editMode** variable on my bean.

When I click Add Button, linked action initAddRubro gets fired and sets editMode = false (let's say that by default is true).

The thing is when I click on Add button without immediate=true, validations gets fired for the Add/Edit modal window (**Field1 is required=true**).

If I use immediate=true on my Add Button then disabled property does not get refreshed.

### Faces Bean

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class RubrosFacesBean implements Serializable{

private boolean editMode = true;


    public String initAddRubro(){
        editMode = false;
        return null;
    }
 }
```

### Page

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"  
oncomplete="PF('addPanelDialog').show();" style="float: right" 
immediate="true" ajax="true" action="#{rubrosFacesBean.initAddRubro}"/>

<p:dialog header="Rubro" widgetVar="addPanelDialog" height="200" style="margin-left: auto;" modal="true" id="addPanelDialog" >
    
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
    
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="addPanel">         

        <h:outputLabel for="field1" value="Field 1: " />
        <p:inputText id="field1" value="#{rubrosFacesBean.field1}" label="Field1" required="true" disabled="#{rubrosFacesBean.editMode}"/>

    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Juan.-

Comment: Hi, were are the links to the 1000's of questions that did not help you? And please read [ask] and specifically the [mcve] part. Code is worth a 1000 words...

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for your reply, I have added minimal code to reproduce the error. If you need something particular to understand the issue please ask. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep `immediate="true"` on your Add Button and just add following attribute to it

```
update="addPanel"
```

**or**

you can set `immediate="false"` and add following attributes

```
process="@this" update="addPanel"
```

Whatever option you choose, after you press Add button validation will be skipped, Ajax will be executed and finally `p:panelGrid` will be updated refreshing `disable` property of `p:inputText`.

Do not forget to do the same with your Edit button.